# How to generate binaries for Linux 64 bit using the source code FMU exported from Dymola. (Cross compilation Windows to Linux)

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, simulink, dymola, fmi

I have a Simulink model which imports FMU exported from Dymola. I want to run many simulations on this Simulink model by varying some parameters. I want to make use of HPC available in the office. Since HPC runs on the Linux platform, I am not able to use the same FMU on Linux, because of missing binaries for Linux (.so file).

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:

Since Dymola uses separate FMU build scripts for linux, the best approach would be to install the linux version of Dymola in a VM on your PC and simply export your model there. Your existing license should mostly work as long as your VM can access network locations.

Approach 2:

The FMU compilation in windows is done using a batch file

`[Path to Dymola Install]\bin\buildfmu.bat`

turn on `echo` in the batch file and you should see all the steps. Set your compiler to GCC, Export as Source code FMU and recreate all the compilation steps in Linux. This will be tedious and might have windows-specific steps so there is a good chance it won't work out.

Comment: Regarding Approach 1, the licenses you get from the server are fully compatible across platforms. No issues there.